# Как ответом на сообщение, ответить ботом disnake/discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Задумка: Я хочу ответить пользователю командой, чтобы он ответил вместо меня на это особщение.
Знаю могу просто указать ID сообщение и после на него ответить, но я хочу сделать, что ты отвечаешь и пишешь команду, а бот уже сам находит сообщение и отвечает на него.
**Знаю, я тупой т.к объяснить нормально не могу, но у меня есть скриншот по которому вы все поймете**[image: первый скрин]

[image: второй скрин]

Вместо ответа DanexExe использует /test Я хочу чтобы бот ответил на сообщение **па** путем упоминания этого сообщения

Comment: Я не знаю, возможно ли это теоретически))